# Custom PixelShaderEffect taking background as input

Tags: uwp-xaml, fragment-shader, direct2d, win2d

I need a self-written `PixelShaderEffect` to take the background image as input.

I want it for a custom written blur effect where is a blurred center which loses blurriness and opacity squarely with growing distance to its center (circular).

All examples I found were going the way: "How to feed an image into your shader". Not what I need, the background is animated, and rendering into an extra image is a bit expensive.

I know with the provided `GaussianBlurEffect` you can do what I want... Although I have trouble getting it to run on UWP, and its form is a rectangle, not circle. (And the opaqueness not a gradient)

Question:
Is there a way to feed the background into a custom `PixelShaderEffect` like into `GaussianBlurEffect` under UWP?

Comment: Have your checked this [document](https://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/M_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_Effects_PixelShaderEffect__ctor.htm)?

Comment: While helpful I still don't get how to do what I want.

Comment: Could you post image that your want to achieve effect?

Answer (score 0):

> Custom PixelShaderEffect taking background as input

For your requirement, you could refer Win2D code sample [`LayersExample`](https://github.com/Microsoft/Win2D-Samples/blob/master/ExampleGallery/LayersExample.xaml#L8) that written blur effect.
[image]

And it use [`CanvasRadialGradientBrush`](https://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/T_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_Brushes_CanvasRadialGradientBrush.htm) to render the blur effect.

```
case LayerMode.OpacityBrush:
gradientBrush.Center = ball.Position;
gradientBrush.RadiusX = gradientBrush.RadiusY = ball.Radius* ball.FadeAlpha * 3;

using (ds.CreateLayer(gradientBrush))

{

    ball.Draw(ds);

}

break;
```